# Using dictionary comprehension to create a dictionary from list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

This is my original code, it works as I need:

```
import collections
import json
import yaml

file_list = [
  {'path': '/path/to/file1', 'size': 100, 'time': '2022-02-15'},
  {'path': '/path/to/file2', 'size': 200, 'time': '2022-02-13'},
  {'path': '/path/to/file3', 'size': 300, 'time': '2022-02-12'},
  {'path': '/path/to/file4', 'size': 200, 'time': '2022-02-11'},
  {'path': '/path/to/file5', 'size': 100, 'time': '2022-02-1-'}]

new_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)

for file in file_list:
    new_dict[file['size']].append(file['path'])

print(json.dumps(new_dict, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

I have found that using collections.defaultdict(list) helps to simplify the loop code so I do not need to check if a key already exists before appending to its list.

EDIT:

Is it possible to make this code ***concise*** by using dictionary comprehension to create the new_dict? The collections.defaultdict(list) is catching me out.

Comment: What does "better" mean?

Comment: If your code runs without error and produces the correct result then you'll get better feedback on performance, style, technique if you repost your question over at the [Code Review StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: _"Is it possible to make this code better by using dictionary comprehension to create the new_dict"_: No. Dict/list comprehensions are for when each iteration of the loop _adds_ an element to the dictionary that you are building, i.e. if you did `new_dict[key] = value` in the loop. In this case, you are _appending_ to a (possibly) pre-existing value, so you can't convert it to a dict comprehension.

Comment: Code that uses a comprehension isn't necessarily _"better"_ than code that doesn't.

Comment: If the `defaultdict` is giving you the heebie-jeebies, change that to a regular dict and ensure that each `new_dict[key]` exists and is a list before trying to append to it

Comment: The question is merely if I can use dictionary comprehension to create the new dictionary in a single line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't claim it's more "concise", but it's a dict comprehension in the end :D

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
sort_list = sorted(file_list, key=itemgetter('size'))
groups = groupby(sort_list, key=itemgetter('size'))
print({k:[i['path'] for i in g] for k, g in groups})
```

Answer (score 2):

If, for some reason, you want to avoid the import of `defaultdict`, this is one way to do it:

```
import json

file_list = [
    {'path': '/path/to/file1', 'size': 100, 'time': '2022-02-15'},
    {'path': '/path/to/file2', 'size': 200, 'time': '2022-02-13'},
    {'path': '/path/to/file3', 'size': 300, 'time': '2022-02-12'},
    {'path': '/path/to/file4', 'size': 200, 'time': '2022-02-11'},
    {'path': '/path/to/file5', 'size': 100, 'time': '2022-02-1-'}]

new_dict = {}

for file in file_list:
    new_dict[file['size']] = (files := new_dict.get(file['size'], []))
    files.append(file['path'])

print(json.dumps(new_dict, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

And if you don't like the constant reassignment of that list to the dicrionary entry (I don't really):

```
for file in file_list:
    if file['size'] not in new_dict:
        new_dict[file['size']] = []
    new_dict[file['size']].append(file['path'])
```

(Note that the default indent depth for Python is 4, you would do others and your future self a favour by adopting that sooner rather than later)

As indicated in the comments, a perhaps more elegant solution:

```
for file in file_list:
    new_dict.setdefault(file['size'], []).append(file['path'])
```

However, although it's possible to come up with a single line comprehension, it won't be more efficient, faster, or readable. In fact, likely none of those - so what would be the point?

Shorter code is often better code if it doesn't compromise on function or readability, but should never be a goal by itself.

For example, consider this (bad) example:

```
c_dict = {size: [fp['path'] for fp in file_list if fp['size'] == size] for size in set(fs['size'] for fs in file_list)}
```

And although that's a single line, you'd probably want to write it like this for readability, at which point you just have more code than before:

```
c_dict = {
    size: [fp['path'] for fp in file_list if fp['size'] == size] 
    for size in set(fs['size'] for fs in file_list)
}
```

Comment: The question is merely if I can use dictionary comprehension to create the new dictionary in a single line

Comment: `files = new_dict.setdefault(file['size'], [])` is a less clumsy way of writing the line with the walrus operator

Comment: The inside of the for loop can actually be a single line:
`new_dict.setdefault(file['size'], list()).append(file['path'])`

Comment: @quantum231 No, this can't be solved with a dict comprehension for this scenario, but you can avoid using `defaultdict` by using `get()` or `setdefault()` methods on a regular dict

Comment: Why can't we do something like this:
new_dict = {k: v for file in file_list: setdefault(file['size'], []).append(file['path'])}
I relatively new to Python and write occasional scripts to make my job easier.

Comment: I don't think there's much of a point detailing why what you suggested won't work (for various reasons), but see the answer for an exmple of a comprehension doing the job. However, if I was teaching a Python class, you'd get fewer marks for that answer than any of the others, since it's simply not better in any way.

Comment: Because its not valid Python syntax.  `setdefault()` and `get()` are dict methods, so they must be called on an instance of a dict.  You could write a generator function that you could iterate over to get the next file size and path out of the file_list, and use that in your dict comprehension, but then you're actually writing more code.

Comment: @quantum _"why can't we do ..."_:  See my comment to your question above, but a good tutorial on comprehensions would probably help you better. Comprehensions are for when each iteration of your loop supplies _one value_ (or key-value pair) to build the list or dict with.

Comment: alright, I understand that my understanding was incomplete

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure your data is cohesive.

```
file_list = [
    {'path': '/path/to/file1', 'size': 100, 'time': '2022-02-15'},
    {'path': '/path/to/file2', 'size': 200, 'time': '2022-02-13'},
    {'path': '/path/to/file3', 'size': 300, 'time': '2022-02-12'},
    {'path': '/path/to/file4', 'size': 200, 'time': '2022-02-11'},
    {'path': '/path/to/file5', 'size': 100, 'time': '2022-02-1-'}]

new_dict = {key:  [file_dict[key] for file_dict in file_list] for key in file_list[0].keys()}
```

For real concise, just use a DataFrame???

```
new_dict = pd.DataFrame(file_list).to_dict(orient='list')
```

Comment: never came across dataframe before